# Backtracking Switch Statement With String

Tags: java

So I'm writing a program that randomly generates a maze and then finds a solution for it. Part of my code includes a backtracking algorithm where I move back if I hit a dead end.

Everytime I move, I record the move ("N" for North, "NE" for Northeast, on and on) in a stack. For the backtracking, I pop the top element of the stack and use a switch statement to move the opposite direction of the direction popped.

When I try to compile my code, it gives me an error that the Stack object popped cannot be converted to int, but I have seen String used for switch statements in other programs. I thought the `toString` method would automatically convert the object to String for the switch statement. I have tried manually using `toString` with the popped value as the parameter but that didn't work either. Here is the code and error message.

```
switch(visitStack.pop())
{
//                      have to backtrack the opposite direction i previously went
    case "N":   nowR++;
                visited[nowR][nowC] = 'N';
                break;
    case "NE":  nowR++;
                nowC--;
                visited[nowR][nowC] = 'N';
                break;
    case "E":   nowC--;;
                visited[nowR][nowC] = 'N';
                break;
    case "SE":  nowR--;
                nowC--;
                visited[nowR][nowC] = 'N';
                break;
    case "S":   nowC--;
                visited[nowR][nowC] = 'N';
                break;
    case "SW":  nowR--;
                nowC++;
                visited[nowR][nowC] = 'N';
                break;
    case "W":   nowC++;
                visited[nowR][nowC] = 'N';
                break;
    case "NW":  nowR++;
                nowC++;
                visited[nowR][nowC] = 'N';
                break;
}
```

[image]

The blued out portion has personal details.

Comment: Shouldn't the `S` case be `nowR--` instead of `nowC--`?

Comment: Just to validate your assumptions, does it work if you save `visitStack.pop()` to a variable, and use `switch` on that? What value is in that variable when you do this?

Comment: I'll try that and yes it should be nowC--

Comment: The `E` case is also `nowC--`. The `W` case is `nowC++`. The `N` case is `nowR++`. That's why I think `S` should be `nowR--`.

Comment: Yes because this backtracks and goes the opposite direction so if I went East earlier, then now I'm going West to backtrack. It did not work when I put the pop value in a variable.

Comment: It has the same error but instead of "Object cannot be converted to int", it says "Object cannot be converted to String"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For `java versions below 7` it wont support `Strings in Switch Case`**

Alternative would be else if ladder to compare strings using `.Equals()` method

or

you can Use Enums in Switch Case

Comment: You might want to note that you shouldn't be using anything below Java 8 anyway.

Comment: The included picture seems to indicate he's using 1.8.0_20 - isn't that Java 8? (I'm not a Java programmer, but googling it returns "Java™ SE Development Kit 8, Update 20 Release Notes")

Comment: If it helps, this compiler is JCreator LE 4.5